# Loop through a JSON object to map column name and value

Tags: javascript, json

below is my JSON

```
{
"portfolioID": 3024,
"gridType": "OWNER",
"gridLayoutId": 4,
"totalRecordCount": 111,
"attributeMetaData": [
    {
        "attributeId": 94,
        "attributeName": "OWNERTYPE",
        "objectType": "OWNER",
        "filterValue1": "",
        "filterValue2": "",
        "filterOperator1": "",
        "filterOperator2": "",
        "columnSortOrder": 0,
        "sortType": "",
        "attributeDisplayName": "TYPE",
        "columnOrder": 1,
        "isGeneralAttribute": "true",
        "isIndustryAttribute": "",
        "isCustomerAttribute": "",
        "dataSource": "Pega",
        "isHidden": "false",
        "isActionable": "",
        "actionType": "",
        "referenceAttribute": "",
        "attributeDataType": "STRING",
        "columnWidth": "",
        "isFreezable": ""
    },
    {
        "attributeId": 95,
        "attributeName": "OWNERSTATUS",
        "objectType": "OWNER",
        "filterValue1": "",
        "filterValue2": "",
        "filterOperator1": "",
        "filterOperator2": "",
        "columnSortOrder": 0,
        "sortType": "",
        "attributeDisplayName": "STATUS",
        "columnOrder": 2,
        "isGeneralAttribute": "true",
        "isIndustryAttribute": "",
        "isCustomerAttribute": "",
        "dataSource": "Pega",
        "isHidden": "false",
        "isActionable": "",
        "actionType": "",
        "referenceAttribute": "",
        "attributeDataType": "STRING",
        "columnWidth": "",
        "isFreezable": ""
    },
    {
        "attributeId": 93,
        "attributeName": "PREFERREDNAME",
        "objectType": "OWNER",
        "filterValue1": "",
        "filterValue2": "",
        "filterOperator1": "",
        "filterOperator2": "",
        "columnSortOrder": 1,
        "sortType": "ASC",
        "attributeDisplayName": "LICENSE OWNER NAME",
        "columnOrder": 3,
        "isGeneralAttribute": "true",
        "isIndustryAttribute": "",
        "isCustomerAttribute": "",
        "dataSource": "Pega",
        "isHidden": "false",
        "isActionable": "true",
        "actionType": "VIEWPAGE",
        "referenceAttribute": "LICENSEOWNERID",
        "attributeDataType": "STRING",
        "columnWidth": "",
        "isFreezable": ""
    },
    {
        "attributeId": 115,
        "attributeName": "LICENSEOWNERID",
        "objectType": "OWNER",
        "filterValue1": "",
        "filterValue2": "",
        "filterOperator1": "",
        "filterOperator2": "",
        "columnSortOrder": 0,
        "sortType": "",
        "attributeDisplayName": "LICENSEOWNERID",
        "columnOrder": 0,
        "isGeneralAttribute": "true",
        "isIndustryAttribute": "",
        "isCustomerAttribute": "",
        "dataSource": "Pega",
        "isHidden": "true",
        "isActionable": "",
        "actionType": "",
        "referenceAttribute": "",
        "attributeDataType": "INTEGER",
        "columnWidth": "",
        "isFreezable": ""
    }
],
"attributeValues": [
    {
        "objectId": 133218,
        "attributeList": [
            {
                "attributeId": 94,
                "attributeValue": "Entity",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 95,
                "attributeValue": "Active",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 93,
                "attributeValue": null,
                "referenceObjectId": "133218"
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 115,
                "attributeValue": "133218",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "objectId": 134179,
        "attributeList": [
            {
                "attributeId": 94,
                "attributeValue": "Individual",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 95,
                "attributeValue": "Active",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 93,
                "attributeValue": "Ra vi Teja",
                "referenceObjectId": "134179"
            },
            {
                "attributeId": 115,
                "attributeValue": "134179",
                "referenceObjectId": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Tried below JS

```
 data.attributeValues.forEach((item, i) => {
const itemattrId = item.attributeList[i].attributeId;            
data.attributeMetaData.forEach((subItem, j) => {
  const subitemattrId = subItem.attributeId;
  if (itemattrId === subitemattrId) {
    console.log(subItem.attributeName + ' - ' + item.attributeList[i].attributeValue);
  }             
});
});
```

I want to loop through this JSON to get the mapping of column name and column values. In the JSON the mapping is done by the property called 'attributeId'. in 'attributeMetaData', 'attributeName' is the name of the column and in 'attributeValues', there is multiple 'attributeList' and in each of them have the 'attributeId' and 'attributeValue' properties. Actually I am trying to build an object to proper name value pairs to bind it to a grid. So, based on 'attributeId', I wanted to map each name value pairs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: To be frank, this seems like a very open "do the work for me" kind of question. What specifically did you try that didn't work? Since it's easy to look up looping over objects and arrays in JS.

Comment: "So, based on 'attributeId', I wanted to map each name value pairs " 


But there is a one-to-one relationship between attributeId and name right?

Comment: For ex, attributeId 94 refers to attributeName OWNERTYPE, and this 94 will be there in each attributeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const idToNameMap = {};
obj.attributeMetaData.forEach(item => {
   idToNameMap[item.attributeId] = item;                               
})

const rows = obj.attributeValues.map(attributeObj => {
   const row = { objectId: attributeObj.objectId };
   attributeObj.attributeList.forEach(attr => { 
      if (idToNameMap[attr.attributeId].isHidden !== "true") {
         row[idToNameMap[attr.attributeId].attributeName] = attr.attributeValue;
      }
   });
   return row;
});

console.log(rows); //Prints:
//[
//  {
//    objectId: 133218,
//    OWNERTYPE: 'Entity',
//    OWNERSTATUS: 'Active',
//    PREFERREDNAME: null,
//  },
//  {
//    objectId: 134179,
//    OWNERTYPE: 'Individual',
//    OWNERSTATUS: 'Active',
//    PREFERREDNAME: 'Ra vi Teja',
//  }
//]
```

Comment: Can we generate an array like that in my question (added a picture), using the mappings you suggested? OwnerAttributes ia a model that we can ignore now.

Comment: Thank you.. One more question.. How can I ignore the mapping of items which have isHidden: "true" property set?

Comment: Either filter out the items that has `isHidden` true from `attributeMetaData` when building the `idToNameMap` or do not include columns whos corresponding metadata item has `isHidden` true when constructing the rows. The latter option is probably more desirable since it doesn't throw away any metadata. See updated answer.

Comment: How can I get 'referenceObjectId' as well? I am getting undefined for that.

Comment: get 'referenceObjectId' as what? Where in the table would it go?

Comment: it is 3rd property in attributeList in the JSON above. it is used as a reference for hyperlinks.

Comment: The result of the transformation in the answer above is a table. Each row in the table contains a map. The map has a number of key/value pairs. Where in this structure do should referenceObjectId be?

Comment: Actually referenceObjectId acts like a foreign key here. When there is any action to be performed on click of 'value', we have to make use of that referenceObjectId by passing it on the click event.

Comment: Can we transform it like another key/value pair like for every object set.. 
    objectId: 134179,
    OWNERTYPE: 'Individual',
    OWNERSTATUS: 'Active',
    PREFERREDNAME: 'Ra vi Teja',
    referenceObjectId: 133218

Comment: Yes, just add `row.referenceObjectId = attr.referenceObjectId`